# Scopes at Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I have a question about Identity Server 3 and OAuth2 scopes.

Generally my understanding of scopes is to "group" resources, with the claims needed for those resources defined in the scope.

Now I want to use the oauth2 client credentials, and the OIDC hybrid flow.
Because one client can only offer one flow in identity server, I have to create different clients for those flows which is fine.

For the Client Credentials flow, scopes must have the type "Resource", because there are no claims in it. For the hybrid flow they will have "identity" with the sub claim etc.

Do I also have to create different scopes for each flow? I wonder because I never saw scopes like "myservice.client", "myservice.hybrid" or sth. like that. My plan was to create the same scope for both flows, but as they contain different information this may not be "right".

What I don't want is to have different API methods for the different flows. If there is a user, the client should connect via hybrid flow with the user context, else via client credentials to authenticate itself.

In my Controller there should only be the Authorize["some scope"].
Is it possible to have AuthorizationPolicies with "OR", so with one name and multiple scopes?

Edit: for the last question, I found:

> You can also specify a list of comma separated values as part of the
>   claim requirement, for example
>
> options.AddPolicy("MustBeGroot", policy =>
>   policy.RequireClaim("Permissions", "Read,Update")); which would pass
>   authorization if the Permissions claim had a value or either Read or
>   Update.

but the right link is: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html.
We have to provide a list, not a comma separated string.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of misunderstandings -

- You can use both Hybrid and Client Credentials Flow with a single Client - use the `AllowClientCredentialsOnly` setting on the client class.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html

- Both identity and resource scopes can have claims. Identity scopes define the content of identity tokens, resource scopes define the content of access tokens. For user authentication, you use an identity token - for API access you use an access token.
- you don't need to create different scopes for different flows.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/scopesAndClaims.html

- the last part is an asp.net core authorization question which should be separate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I missed the AllowClientCredentialsOnly property, this is great. One more clarification about scopes: a scope for accessing an API would always be a resource scope for both client and hybrid flow. What I'd need for hybrid flow are additional identity scopes. I think I got it now, thanks.